# Delete multiple image from GridView on one time button press

Tags: android, gridview

I am working on `gridview` ,here is my requirement to delete multiple selected image items from gridview on one time `delete button` press.

means *i should be able to deleted selected images on press of delete button.*

I tried lot but not getting idea about this.

*I am able to delete one image at one time .*

this is what i did.

//Activity

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {

    ImageAdapter iAdapter;
    ArrayList<Integer>myList;
    int position;
    GridView gView;
    boolean selected = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
        dataImage();
        iAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,myList);
        gView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gView.setAdapter(iAdapter);
        gView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                gView.setSelection(position);
                gView.setSelected(true);
                Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_image, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_delete)
        {
            if(gView.isSelected())
            {
                iAdapter.list.remove(iAdapter.getPosition());
                iAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Delete" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        }
        gView.setSelected(false);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void dataImage()
    {
        myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_1);
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_3);
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_2);
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_2);
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_1);
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_3);
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_1);
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_3);
        myList.add(R.drawable.sample_2);


    }
}
```

//Adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Integer> list;
    int position;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageActivity act;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Integer>list)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        act = (ImageActivity)context;
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.position = position;
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);


        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(list.get(position));

        return imageView;
    }

    public int getPosition()
    {
        return position;

    }
}
```

//

Can any one guide me or help me.

***My requirement*** :-
**How to delete multiple images from `gridview` in one time press delete button.**

Answer (score 1):

Hi I figured out how to delete multiple images using `CheckBox` in a `GridView`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
    File[] listFile;

    Button btnDelete;

    private ProgressDialog pd;

    HashSet<String> selectedFile = new HashSet<String>();// list of file paths boolean checked

    GridView imagegrid;

    AlertDialog alertDialog = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFromSdcard();
    imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteImg);

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // to delete selected images
            Iterator iterator = selectedFile.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
            new File(iterator.next().toString()).delete();
            }
           }
        });
    }

    public void getFromSdcard() {
        File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Images");

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = file.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

               f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

            }
        }
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return f.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(position));
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            final int pos = position;

            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!selectedFile.contains((String)f.get(pos)))
                {
                    selectedFile.add((String)f.get(pos));
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedFile.remove((String)f.get(pos));
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }
}
```

This approach is working for me, if you guys need more information please comment, Thanks stackoverflow

Comment: I'm also try to delete multiple selected images, but some time my app is crash and getting  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1 error

Comment: Well your array/collection size is 1 and you are trying to delete item with index higher than array/collection size. You have to keep refreshing view after delete cycle is done. If you can share source code then it will be more easy to fix the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have post my code here = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251664/android-indexoutofbounds-exception-while-delete-multiple-images-from-gridview?noredirect=1#comment54305913_33251664

Comment: Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom list adapter in which  use Check Box and ImageView(custom view) and inflate view in getView(). On check box select put that into ArrayList and put delete button by which you can delete all the images from list and than notify adapter.